# Passing a Variable to be Encrypted Fernet Python

Tags: python, encryption

I am trying to pass a Variable into the encrypt method. The encryption method is the Fernet encryption method from python cryptography.

```
Var = "Hello World"
Ecy = Fernet(Key)
token = Ecy.encrypt(b'Var')
```

However this encrypts the word `Var` instead of the variable.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just pass in the variable itself: `Ecy.encrypt(Var)`.

However, if you're using python3, then all strings are unicode, so you have to encode your string variable to bytes (which python2 strings are by default), like `Ecy.encrypt(Var.encode())`.